# Creating symbology on multiple attributes using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am using ArcMap and want to style datasets based on a number of attributes fields to communicate visually several aspects of the feature.  An example is below, where up to 4 attributes are used to define colour, linetype and symbol.  I do not have the option to split the layer tables into smaller parts due to the use of a defined schema.

Is this possible in ArcMap?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can only symbolise on 3 attributes in ArcMap.

However, what you could do is separate your layer based on definition queries. That is, copy and paste the layer and set the definition queries for each.

[image]

For example, you could create a definition query for your valves to only show `Status = Inuse`.

[image]

Then, you'd only be symbolising on the following attributes - `Water`, `Type`, and `Open_Shut`.

[image]
Create another layer for valves where `Status = Abandoned` and repeat the process.

Your results will look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Separating layers based on definition queries is how I used to do it too.  I think we did Def. query on status, then symbolised on the other three fields (eg "Water", "Type", "Open/Shut" as per the screenshot in the Question)